# Start default e-sim activation

Tags: android, e-sim

I am writing an app similar to a QR code scanner. I see that, for example, the Google Camera app, after scanning a QR code with LPA (like 1$prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog$052X-UFXS-CQIY-PNGL), opens a system activity where the user can activate an eSIM.

My question is about how to open this system activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Implementation of ESim there is a documentation available on Android Developers [here](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview?hl=en).

However, If you dont need the Euicc Manager or the LPA for handling profiles, you can also just pass the Intent to the system like

```html
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data = Uri.parse(yourLPACode)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
context.startActivity(intent)
```